# Tikz: two lines in a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I have 2 lines in a `\tikz` node? For instance, suppose I want to have:

A1

+

A2

in the first node, inside the ellipse. How could I achieve that?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture},
na/.style={baseline=-.5ex}}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
  \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=red!20, ellipse,anchor=base] (t2)
        {A1};
    } 
     \quad 
  \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=green!20, ellipse,anchor=base] (t4)
        {B};
    } 
    \quad
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=purple!20, ellipse,anchor=base] (t5)
        {C};
    } 
    \quad
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=brown!20, ellipse,anchor=base] (t6)
        {D};
    } 
   \end{equation*}
\bigskip


\centering\tikz[na]\node(n3)[fill=blue!20,anchor=base]{mixture};


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
     \path[->]<1-> (t2.south) edge [out=270,in=90] (n3);
     \path[->]<1-> (t5.south) edge [out=270,in=90] (n3);
     \path[->]<1-> (t4.south) edge [out=270,in=90](n3);
     \path[->]<1-> (t6.south) edge [out=270,in=90](n3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\\` to add new lines along with an `align` specification such as        `align=center`:

```
\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[fill=red!20, ellipse,anchor=base, align=center] (t2)
    {A1 \\ + \\ A2};
}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={remember picture},
na/.style={baseline=-.5ex}}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{equation*}
  \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=red!20, ellipse,anchor=base, align=center] (t2)
        {A1 \\ + \\ A2};
    } 
     \quad 
  \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=green!20, ellipse,anchor=base] (t4)
        {B};
    } 
    \quad
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=purple!20, ellipse,anchor=base] (t5)
        {C};
    } 
    \quad
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=brown!20, ellipse,anchor=base] (t6)
        {D};
    } 
   \end{equation*}
\bigskip


\centering\tikz[na]\node(n3)[fill=blue!20,anchor=base]{mixture};


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
     \path[->]<1-> (t2.south) edge [out=270,in=90] (n3);
     \path[->]<1-> (t5.south) edge [out=270,in=90] (n3);
     \path[->]<1-> (t4.south) edge [out=270,in=90](n3);
     \path[->]<1-> (t6.south) edge [out=270,in=90](n3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```